# Assigning A Symbol To A Second DSolve Solution

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am looking for a way to compress a lengthy `DSolve` solution to a single symbol, kind of like assigning a variable. I have this expression:

```
Simplify[DSolve[q''[t] + q'[t] + q[t] == Sin[t], q'[0] == 0, q[0] == 0}, q[t], t]]
```

which when solved results in a long-expression. If I, for example, assign s=the previous expression, and then try to plot s, it just gives me a blank graph, hence, a simple symbol=dsolveexpression, seems to not work, and makes the document very messy. Is there any way to go around that?

Comment: You are almost there. After having assigned s to your solution you need to write something like `Plot[{q[t] /. s}, {t, 0, 1}]`. The point is that `DSolve` returns a rule, rather than a function. Have a look at Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/DSolve/Scope/Basic Uses. You will find examples.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, I still get a blank graph...

Comment: Manipulate[Plot[{q[t] /. s}, {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> Automatic]

Comment: If you want to save the expression behind the rule returned by `DSolve` you could use `s=q[t] /.First@Simplify@DSolve[...]`.

Comment: Maybe: `q = DSolveValue[{q''[t] + q'[t] + q[t] == Sin[t], q'[0] == 0, q[0] == 0}, q, t]; Plot[{q[t], q'[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]` ?

Answer (score 2):

The best way i found is to work with pure functions. Threrefore do `DSolve[....., q, t]` and not `DSolve[....., q[t], t]`. I call the new generated function qsol. Now you can easily plot the function and any derivatives you like.

```
qsol = q /. 
 First@DSolve[{q''[t] + q'[t] + q[t] == Sin[t], q'[0] == 0, 
 q[0] == 0}, q, t]

Plot[{qsol[t], qsol'[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

You can also work with parameters this way. Here parameters a and b for initial conditions.

```
qsol2[a_, b_] = 
 q /. First@
 DSolve[{q''[t] + q'[t] + q[t] == Sin[t], q'[0] == b, q[0] == a}, q,
 t]

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[{qsol2[a, b][t], qsol2[a, b]''[t]}], {t, 0, 10}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}], {a, 0, 7, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {b, 
0, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Now it is easy to test the result with `/. q->qsol`

```
{q''[t] + q'[t] + q[t] == Sin[t], q'[0] == b, q[0] == a} /. 
q -> qsol2[a, b] // Simplify

(*   {True, True, True}   *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = Simplify[
   DSolve[{q''[t] + q'[t] + q[t] == Sin[t], q'[0] == 0, q[0] == 0}, q,
     t]][[1, 1]]


(* q -> Function[{t}, -(1/3) E^(-t/
    2) (-3 Cos[(Sqrt[3] t)/2] + 
     3 E^(t/2) Cos[t] Cos[(Sqrt[3] t)/2]^2 - 
     Sqrt[3] Sin[(Sqrt[3] t)/2] + 
     3 E^(t/2) Cos[t] Sin[(Sqrt[3] t)/2]^2)]  *)
```

Then this:

```
Plot[{q[t] /. s}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Have fun!